# Is there a way for links within an iFrame to redirect to their source?

Tags: html, redirect, iframe, browser

For temporary measures I want to duplicate/mirror [my blog](http://dur.designsoc.com/blog/) onto its [root domain](http://www.designsoc.com). This is because I do not have time at the moment to design a front page.

I have the website mirrored using [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) (Is there a more convenient method for my requirements?)

I just want the links within the root domain (ie mirrored page) to redirect to the original page when clicked (I.e. So that the source content is displayed in the browser address-bar). Is there a way to do this?

I only want to use the iFrame to display the page. Once a link is clicked, I want the iFramed page to be left behind and the rest of the webpage experience to be at the iFrame's source.

Comment: Why not redirect with window.location = 'root domain';

Comment: @GrantKiely Could you give further details and context please?

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect your root domain to the blog subdomain or use DNS to point your root domain to your blog server.

**Edit**

If you must use an iframe, you can include the base tag inside the  tag of your iframe to cause all links to open in the top-level window. For example:

```
<iframe>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <html>
        ...
    </html>
</iframe>
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp for more details.

I still think the better solution is to put a redirect on your base domain or use DNS to point the base domain to the blog.

Comment: Thanks I got that working. Just a quick follow up question for future visitors... I have a 'root domain' (designsoc.com) and a 'root subdomain' (dur.designsoc.com) Is there a way to redirect only the 'root domain' to dur.designsoc.com/blog , while leaving the 'root subdomain' as is? I couldn't seem to get that to work (although I don't need it myself). And finally, is there any advantage using DNS over the redirect function I found in cPanel? Thanks